# Dynamically create a menu from exploded datas from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, navigation

I struggle to find an easy way to recreate a navigation structure with datas stored in a mysql database. I can't change the database structure, it's automatically generated.

I use Laravel 5.2 as the base framework for this project.

Here's the database structure:

Datas:

```
| id | origin | type       | value                              |
|----|--------|------------|------------------------------------|
| 1  | 20     | menuLevel  | 0                                  |
| 2  | 20     | menuTitle  | The title of this menu item        |
| 3  | 20     | menuParent | 0                                  |
| 4  | 20     | menuUrl    | /url-of-the-menu                   |
| 5  | 21     | menuLevel  | 1                                  |
| 6  | 21     | menuTitle  | The title of this second menu item |
| 7  | 21     | menuParent | 20                                 |
| 8  | 21     | menuUrl    | /url-of-the-submenu                |
```

And much more data of this kind. But all menu items always contains four properties, the level, the title, the url and the parent item that I have to put together.

With this structure, I try to recreate the navigation but I can't find the proper way to query the database to obtain a result that I can then use with a jquery tree plugin to navigate through the generated menu.

Ideally, this structure would be:

```
{
    'origin': {
        'menuLevel': 0,
        'menuTitle': 'The title',
        'menuParent': 0,
        'menuUrl': '/url'
    }, and so on..
}
```

Does anyone already faced this kind of structure? What could be the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: show what you want

Comment: your ideal structure is extremely confusing, why is the key "origin", that's the column name ...

Comment: how many origins do you have , only 20 and 21?

Comment: No, here it's just an example. The origin is an unique id that link the datas together. Origin can be infinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if by `'origin'` you mean `20`, you probably could query

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] ORDER BY origin
```

and then put them into an array until the `origin` changes, then open a new array. This also fetches the unstructured data.

if you want exactly those four attributes, you could do a query like

```
SELECT t1.origin, t1.value as menuLevel, t2.value as menuTitle, 
       t3.value as menuParent, t4.value as menuUrl
FROM [table] t1
LEFT JOIN [table] t2 ON (t1.origin=t2.origin AND t2.type='menuTitle')
LEFT JOIN [table] t3 ON (t1.origin=t3.origin AND t3.type='menuParent')
LEFT JOIN [table] t4 ON (t1.origin=t4.origin AND t4.type='menuUrl')
WHERE t1.type='menuLevel'
```

This could be extended to all the unstructured data as well, you'd then have a lot of `NULL`s that you could filter out or not.

**add:** I hope laravel puts an index on (id, type) or this query might be quite slow.